# Converting between integer std::chrono::durations

Tags: c++, std, c++-chrono

I'm writing a standard game loop using std::chrono. I need to pass a float to my render method that represents how far into the next frame I am. To calculate the number I'm using the count() method of chrono::duration, hence I need to convert two durations to the same ratio.

```
void engine::run() {
  using namespace std::chrono;
  using updates = duration<steady_clock::rep, std::ratio<1, 40>>;
  using common = std::common_type<updates, steady_clock::duration>::type;

  constexpr updates time_per_update{1};
  auto previous = steady_clock::now();
  auto lag = steady_clock::duration::zero();

  while (!quit) {
    auto now = steady_clock::now();
    auto delta = now - previous;

    previous = now;
    lag += delta;

    while (lag >= time_per_update) {
      lag -= time_per_update;
      update(time_per_update);
    }

    render(common{lag}.count() / static_cast<double>(common{time_per_update}.count()));
  }
}
```

If I change the ratio in 'updates' to, say 41, I get a compile error at the subtraction, because a 1/41 of a second cannot be precisely converted to steady_clock::duration. However, when I rewrite the code to this, it compiles just fine:

```
void engine::run() {
  using namespace std::chrono;
  using updates = duration<steady_clock::rep, std::ratio<1, 41>>;
  using common = std::common_type<updates, steady_clock::duration>::type;

  constexpr common time_per_update{updates{1}};
  auto previous = steady_clock::now();
  common lag = steady_clock::duration::zero();

  while (!quit) {
    auto now = steady_clock::now();
    auto delta = now - previous;

    previous = now;
    lag += delta;

    while (lag >= time_per_update) {
      lag -= time_per_update;
      update(time_per_update);
    }

    render(lag.count() / static_cast<double>(time_per_update.count()));
  }
}
```

I was under the impression the conversion to common_type happens implicitly during the subtraction. What am I missing? Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: It is easier for people to help you if you provide a [mre].

Comment: I would recommend you to use the chrono functions only to obtain the unix timestamp in seconds/milliseconds/microseconds/nanoseconds as a `size_t` and then compute lags in a POD type (`size_t`, `int64_t`,...) as differences. Use for example `size_t microseconds=std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch()).count();` and adjust `microseconds` to `nanoseconds` if you need such a precision.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To clarify, this is the line of code that gets an error:

```
 lag -= time_per_update;

test.cpp:27:11: error: no viable overloaded '-='
      lag -= time_per_update;
      ~~~ ^  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

> I was under the impression the conversion to common_type happens implicitly during the subtraction.

You are correct, but not exactly correct.

The *binary* subtraction operator returns the `common_type` of the two arguments:

```
template <class Rep1, class Period1, class Rep2, class Period2>
  constexpr
  typename common_type<duration<Rep1, Period1>, duration<Rep2, Period2>>::type
  operator-(const duration<Rep1, Period1>& lhs, const duration<Rep2, Period2>& rhs);
```

However the `-=` operator has to be equivalent to:

```
lag = lag - delta;
```

And if the `result` of `lag - delta` is not implicitly convertible to the type of `lag`, then you have a problem (as is the case for your example).

Changing the type of `lag` to `common` is the correct fix:

```
common lag = steady_clock::duration::zero();
```

Here's another way to do that.  The choice between these two is stylistic:

```
auto lag = steady_clock::duration::zero() + updates{0};
```

Finally, just as  personal nit, I like to minimize (if not eliminate) the uses of `.count()` as this is the equivalent of a `reinterpret_cast` from `duration` to `integral` (or scalar).  This is not hard to do in your example, and involves no loss in efficiency.

First add an equivalent to `common` that uses `double` as the representation:

```
using dcommon = duration<double, common::period>;
```

Then you just convert `lag` to `dcommon` and divide that by `time_per_update` to get your ratio:

```
render(dcommon{lag} / time_per_update);
```

Finally, there is one more stylistic variation for you to consider:  Just represent `lag` as `double`-based up front:

```
auto lag = steady_clock::duration::zero() + updates{0} + duration<double>{0};
```

Now your call to `render` is even simpler:

```
render(lag / time_per_update);
```

And `common` and `dcommon` are no longer even needed (you can remove them).